# method does not override a method from its superclass java @override in android

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I am trying to make calculator app but I am getting error for overriding OnClickListner

---

BtnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListner(){

```
           @Override // getting red line here asking method does not override super class 
            public void onClick(View v){
               Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
        });
```

---

Comment: You're missing an `e` in `View.OnClickListner`. Should be `View.OnClickListener`.

Comment: thanks mike , Its my silly mistake of coping code from elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

It is not `getActivity` it is `getApplicationContext`

```
@Override // getting red line here asking method does not override super class 
public void onClick(View v) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
});
```